# Reply via email (mailto link) in RSS feed at the end of each post

Tags: rss, feed

I came across this post https://ethanmarcotte.com/wrote/replyin/ where author says he added Reply via email link at the end of each post in RSS feed so people have this option to respond via email

In his feed (XML format) it looks like this

```
<p><a href="mailto:listener+rss@ethanmarcotte.com?subject=Reply%20to:%20“Bookiversary.”">Reply via email</a></p>
```

I am using Underscores and it has several default feed templates that come with WP install. I checked WP Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds and didn't find anything specific on how to modify templates to add this feature.

**Question:** is this done by modifying RSS templates? If so, which one and how?

**Update:** Based on @birgire suggestion to use  **the_content_feed** filter, the following code adds email address at the end of my RSS feed (as per XML view)

```
    // add custom content to all feeds

function add_content_to_all_feeds($content) {

      $after = '<p><a href="mailto:hello@mail.com">Reply via email</a></p>';

    if (is_feed()) {

        return $content . $after;

    } else {

        return $content;

    }

}
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'add_content_to_all_feeds');
```

Comment: You might look into e.g. appending it with the `the_content_feed` filter instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @birgire, I have updated my question with the code I put in functions.php and its working as per XML view (I haven't done any testing). I am on local Laragon environment. I am wondering what are those question mark and percent signs in `?subject=Reply%20to:%20“Bookiversary.” ?` Also can adding 'reply by email' option to feeds cause lots of email spam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should most likely be enough:

```
function add_content_to_all_feeds( $content ) {
      $after = '...';
      return $content . $after;
}
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'add_content_to_all_feeds' );
```

without the `is_feed()` check.

> I am wondering what are those question mark and percent signs in
> ?subject=Reply%20to:%20“Bookiversary.” ?

This is so called [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) where `%20` means space.

> Also can adding 'reply by email' option to feeds cause lots of email
> spam?

It might, but some bots don't even need to scan your site for emails, to spam you.

They can just guess the most likely emails from your domain name, e.g.

```
example@example.com, 
info@example.com, 
...
```

and try to spam directly.

Probably also guess it from the public usernames.

You could also link to your spam protected contact form instead.

Consider using an email account, with a good spam protection, regardless.

Comment: `marcotte.com?subject=Reply%20to:%20“Bookiversary.”`  whats the purpose of question mark after email address? Is that a reserved character that serves as delimiter? Also, “Bookiversary” in the above example is the post title, how does it get pulled in?

Comment: as per https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6068#page-3 "Within 'mailto' URIs, the characters "?", "=", and "&" are reserved,
   serving as delimiters.  They have to be escaped (as "%3F", "%3D", and
   "%26", respectively) when not serving as delimiters." So based on the aforementioned ? question mark is a delimiter